# JavaFX: When the user touches any button (to click them) in a particular scene, how can I suppress mouse cursor movement?

Tags: javafx, touch, mouse

I have a JavaFX Windows application that contains:

- a Teacher screen (JavaFX scene), which exists on the first monitor.
- a Student screen, which exists on a second monitor.

On the Student screen there are controls, such as buttons, that the student touches in order to click.

When the student does that (touches a button in order to click it), I don’t want the mouse cursor to move at all from where it resides on the Teacher screen.
How can I accomplish that?  Thanks!

Comment: I need some additional explanation. What does it mean to touch in order to click? Is it a touch app? If the button is supposed to be clicked the cursor should be over the button in student's screen so how should I stop cursor on teacher's screen which is not there at the moment? After stating this I'm afraid I don't understand the problem at all.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The student interacts with the monitor by touching buttons with his finger.  Only the teacher controls the mouse.  The mouse position on the teacher screen should not be affected (or should appear not to be affected) by what the student does.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. That means a Minimal(no extra code) Complete and Verifiable(runnable on others machines) Example.